# How do I split text into key-value pairs?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I'm building a script to read and parse markdown files in Ruby. The script needs to be able to read and understand the multimarkdown header information at the top of the files so that it can perform additional actions on the output.

The header values look like this:

```
Title: My Treatise on Kumquats
Author: Joe Schmoe
Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/
Host URL: http://googlesnewthing.com/
Created: 2012-01-01 09:41
```

I can't figure out how to split the lines of text into a simple key-value dictionary. The built in split function doesn't seem to work in this case because I only want it to split on the first occurrence of a colon (:) in each line. Additional colons would be part of the value string.

In case it matters I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `split` with an optional second parameter (thanks to @MichaelKohl)

```
s = 'Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/'
key, value = s.split ': ', 2
puts key
puts value
```

Output

```
Author URL
http://somedudeswebsite.me/
```

Comment: Except I'd lose the colon in the URL and it would no longer be a valid URL.

Comment: Looks like a fairly elegant solution, I suspect I'll go with it. I'll leave the question open until morning just in case. :)

Comment: There probably always will be, but I think the Multimarkdown engine is colon-only, so I'd like to maintain that compatibility -- though admittedly this option never even crossed my mind.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `split` has an optional second argument for specifying the maximum number of parts you want after the split: `"'Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/'".split(':', 2) #=> ["'Author URL", " http://somedudeswebsite.me/'"]`

Comment: @MichaelKohl: Thanks, never used it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This does it:

```
s = <<EOS
Title: My Treatise on Kumquats
Author: Joe Schmoe
Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/
Host URL: http://googlesnewthing.com/
Created: 2012-01-01 09:41
EOS

h = Hash[s.each_line.map { |l| l.chomp.split(': ', 2) }]
p h
```

Output:

```
{"Title"=>"My Treatise on Kumquats", "Author"=>"Joe Schmoe", "Author URL"=>"http://somedudeswebsite.me/", "Host URL"=>"http://googlesnewthing.com/", "Created"=>"2012-01-01 09:41"}
```

Comment: You probably want to split on ': ', or otherwise strip that trailing space.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to parse your text:

```
str = "Title: My Treatise on Kumquats
Author: Joe Schmoe
Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/
Host URL: http://googlesnewthing.com/
Created: 2012-01-01 09:41"

matches = str.scan /^(.+?): (.+?)$/m

matches.each { |m|
   key = m[0]
   value = m[1]
}
```

This is multi-line regex (`/<regex>/m`) - it will match each line into two groups (with indexes 0 and 1). First group will contain all characters before the first occurence of `": "` (colon + space). Second group will contain all the rest characters in this line (until regex encounter end of line `$`).

This is how you can convert result into Hash:

```
dictionary = matches.inject({}) do |dict, m| 
  dict[m[0]] = m[1]
  dict
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

As Michael Kohl mentioned, it is possible to write this in one line:

```
hash = Hash[str.scan /^(.+?): (.+?)$/m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by

```
>> s = 'Author URL: http://somedudeswebsite.me/'
>> first_idx = s.index(':')
>> key,value = s[0..first_idx-1],s[first_idx+1..s.length]
=> ["Author URL", " http://somedudeswebsite.me/"]
```

or to key value hash by

```
>> kv = Hash[*s[0..first_idx-1],s[first_idx+1..s.length]]
=> {"Author URL"=>" http://somedudeswebsite.me/"}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is `line.split(':',2)` what you want?

String#split accepts a second argument which specifies parts to be splited.
it works in ruby 1.9.3, not sure in earlier versions. (but i'm almost sure it also works in 1.9.2 too)

If this is not available, `line.scan(%r{^([^:]*):(.*)})` should also work.